# Active record queries - chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to convert the following query into something better, using parameters for example.

I am new to active record and rails so still learning.  But the null part is throwing me off.  Since this needs to work on both mysql and sql server.

```
contacts = contacts.where("key_contact = true and (c_contact is null or c_contact = false)")
```

I should not that key_contact and c_contact are in a different table called main_contacts.
The contacts table `has_many` main_contacts

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say:

```
contacts = contacts.where(key_contact: true).where(c_contact: [nil, false])
```

In console check the resulting query appending `.explain`

Should be equivalent to:

```
contacts = contacts.where(key_contact: true).where.not(c_contact: true)
```

Anyway, you should keep consistency in your database. So for booleans, have a default value to prevent `null`.

---

Per your comment:

```
contacts = contacts.joins(:main_contacts).where(main_contacts: { key_contact: true }).where.not(main_contacts: { c_contact: true })
```

Comment: If nulls are a possibility, I think I'd prefer "where(c_contact: [false, nil])"

Comment: I should mention that key_contact and c_contact are columns in a different table, they are in a table called main_contacts.  How do I specify this in the query above, as it is using the contacts table and not finding the columns